# Object Object, como não emitir este alerta

Tags: javascript, ajax

Bom, tenho páginas que enviam requisições assíncronas, porém quando interrompidas elas emitem um alerta [Object Object].

Isso atrapalha um pouco, pois aparece enquanto o servidor esta direcionando para a página(como a que o cliente escolheu).

Há um jeito de isso não acontecer?

Acredito que seja pelo fato de eu esperar um retorno usando o `dataType`,(AJAX + JQuery), mas isso eu não poderia mudar.

Comment: Procura no teu código por "alert", como o hugomg referiu esse alert vêm do teu código e não um comportamento do browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esses alertas não são comportamento padrão do seu javascript. Você vai ter que fuçar o seu código e achar quem está chamando a função `alert`.

O "Object object" ocorre quando alguém passa um objeto pro `alert` ao invés de uma string. A função `alert` converte o seu parâmetro pra string e a conversão padrão em Javascript prum objeto qualquer é `[object Object]`.

Se você só quiser fazer os alerts não aparecerem pro usuário uma alternativa é substituir `alert(coisa)` por `console.log(coisa)`.

Comment: Perfeito, eu estava pedindo para alertar em caso de erro na requisição, obrigado!